# Understanding Workaround in Cardview in a scrollable GridView

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, scrollview, cardview

I just started with Android Studio and I am trying to create my first own app.
For getting a headstart I combinded some tutorials that I liked and ended up with a problem.

In my main_activity I am using **CardView in a scrollable GridView.** 
Since I have more than 40 cards in my CardView I have a load of frames to scroll through.

The issue comes with those many Cards, since they are sometimes not correctly visualized. I found a workaround for that, by setting another Gridview (lets say maingrid2) under my used Gridview (maingrid) that is not even visualized on my screen.

With the workaround it looks like that:
[Gridview working, but has workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeKJf.png)

If i delete my workaround [delete maingrid2] it looks like that:
[Gridview stretched all the way, for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YSnA.png).

So basically I need another GridView that does "something wired" with the code.
Can you maybe explain to me why this works or a proper fix so it works normally?

Here is my code:

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.MainActivity"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <!--android:background="@drawable/bg"-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 
 
 
 <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9.5"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="3"
            android:rowCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >

            <!--Cardviews-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:background="@drawable/enchantress"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                app:cardElevation="5dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:background="@drawable/enchantress"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
           <!-- have around 40 more Cardviews like that -->
           

        </GridLayout>
        
        
        <GridLayout
           android:id="@+id/maingrid2>
      
        <!-- [....] -->
        <!-- exact same as above!-->

        </GridLayout>
        
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The code is obviously not containing all 40 Cardviews. I only put in two in the example. It could have something to do with the android:weightsum, since I played around with that.

With best regards
CG

P.S. I used TextView to display Images because I thought I might use text over the Image aswell. Right now I am not doing that, so I can go back to ImageView.

P.S.S. I read in another thread that one should not use Gridview with a Scrollview but, maybe this is the issue. But there is no other way to this from my knowledge standpoint, therefore I kept using it.

Comment: That's not how you work with lists and grids. Use adapters and inflate your list to gridview using the adapters

Comment: And yes you should not use scrollview with gridview. Gridview have their own scrolling mechanism so no need to put in scrollview

Comment: Can you please give me more information about what kind of adapters you are talking about?

I watched a tutorial about it but I don't see the improvement yet.

Comment: I found out that I can delete my gridview when I work without the layout_weights. So I am going to do that.

Anyway, thank you already sir!

A explanation why I should use adapters would be nice :)

Comment: Adapters act as a link between your view and the data. Adapters are generally used when you have not fixed amount of data for eg. gallery images. Images can increase or decrease anytime and you can't have fixed number of rows and column in that case.

Comment: How adapter works is that you create a layout of one single item of your gridview. Second you create your data set in a form of an arraylist or any other suitable collection object. Then you pass your dataset and your item layout to adapter class. Then adapter iterates through the data and add one item layout for each data.

Comment: Alright seems like a better solution than mine for sure.

One last question -  Does that also improve smoothness of the app? I use that next time for sure, but mine seems to do its job for now! :).. thank you so much

Comment: You won't be able to notice that much of difference with less data but as your data will increase you can definitely see the smoothness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this wrap up this thread I want to write down what I found out.

In my code in the top I used "weightsum" wrong, therefore I had to do this workaround with the gridview. Obviously not a correct way of doing it.

**Regard the comments and the tutorials I have watched now I recommend using a Recyclerview for this matter.**

Comment: **You could have just added a comment that there was no need to unaccept my answer**

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than one CardView with same layout the please check out the tutorials on RecyclerView it will reduce your code and increase your app speed.

All you have to do is code one CardView XML and call it in your RecyclerView using adapter and you can inflate data using an ArrayList or A database

Comment: I checked out a tutorials on the RecyclerView and general implementation seems easy. Can you give me a hint though I make it so that I can have 3 columns. If I make a general layout with 3 columns I always obviously have 3 columns with CardViews. But what do I do when I only want to display 1 or 2 Cardviews in the last row?

Comment: To refer to my last commend, I got that figured out by myself. RecyclerView provides a good and easy option for that.

I recommend this tutorial for what I want to do [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SD2t75T5RdY).